# TV discussion consensus

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final TV Decision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision)

In an effort to make the scope clear to new users and keeping items focused, I propose that all movies and only movies (even non-theatrical) be included in scope.

To support the TV Proposal please use the following link,

[Support the TV proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2026/tv-buffs?referrer=oXHfUUmvIEwDoBR1PHU4dA2)

Currently it only needs 180 more users to reach launch stage for private beta.